# How can I call OnCollsionEnter2D function in VoidUpdate?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I do not know How to call the OncollisionEnter 2D Function in other places of the code.

In THIS CODE I WOULD LIKE TO CALL IT IN THE VOID UPDATE.
I am doing a PLATFORM Jumping game so ot is crucial for me to know how to call the oncollisionenter2D function.

```
    void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.name == "Front_Buildings")
        {

            GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("isGrounded", true);

        }
 }
```

Comment: You cant call `OnCollisionEnter` it will be called when there is a collision. It works like an Event Listener.

Comment: You should not call this explicitly it is `event`...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really be explicitly calling OnCollisionEnter2D.

If you need similar behavior, I suggest refactoring to something like this.

```
void Update() {
    if (someReason) {
        HandleCollision(someGameObject)
    }
}

void HandleCollision(GameObject gameObject) {
    if (gameObject.name == "Front_Buildings")
    {
        GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("isGrounded", true);
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D col)
{
    HandleCollision(col.gameObject);    
}
```